# make a table as x axis label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

so I have a geom_tile and I need to label columns. Each label has the following form:

value1_value2_value3_value_4_value_5. If I label like this the text is very cumbersome to read. Is there any way to have all the labels appear as a column of text like this:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
```

baxically making a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't get something, but can't you replace `_` with a newline? For example:

```
foo <- paste0("value", 1:5)
paste(foo, collapse = "\n")
[1] "value1\nvalue2\nvalue3\nvalue4\nvalue5"
```

And it will appear as:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
```

If your labels already are in `value1_value2_value3_value_4_value_5` format you can do this:

```
gsub("_", "\n", "value1_value2_value3_value_4_value_5")
```